# How to persist private key of RSAParameter in C#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, x509certificate2

Starting with .Net 4.7.2 (.Net Standard 2.0) it's possible to create self-signed certificates and certificate signing requests with C#/.Net only, see the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netframework-4.7.2).

While it's straight forward to create a self-signed certificate which will assert `HasPrivateKey` (you just call `CreateSelfSigned(notBefore, notAfter)`) I'm having a hard time to figure out how to get hold of the private key in general, e.g. if I want to create a certificate signed by a CA and then want to persist the certificate as a PFX file or want to persist the private key in a `.PEM` file or want to store it in the MS certificate store together with the private key, or when I just want to have in memory and also assert `HasPrivateKey`.

What I do have is a 'RSAParameters' instance which is in possession of the relevant private information, but I failed to figure out how to (easily) use that for the purpose in question (create a PFX file or PEM file or MS Certificate Store entry) without having to read through all the relevant RFCs and write a program for that on my own. (That RSAParameter instance contains the `D`, `Exponent` and `Modulus`, so I could try to patch this together (with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193529/how-to-store-retrieve-rsa-public-private-key), hopefully), but I was hoping for a C# method which will perform these tasks for me (which I could not find) by now).

Of course the idea is to do that with .Net functionality alone, as well.

Every hint on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: There is a little method you can use to get the private key location from the Windows Store location, I am unsure about the PFX and PEM file key locations though, havent delved into them much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have `Modulus`, `Exponent`, and `D` you first have to recover the CRT parameters (`P`, `Q`, `DP`, `DQ`, `InverseQ`).

As your other questions, you're mainly missing the `cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key)` extension methods and `rsa.ImportParameters(RSAParameters)`:

> if I want to create a certificate signed by a CA and then want to persist the certificate as a PFX file

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    using (X509Certificate2 caSigned = GetCASignedCert(rsa))
    using (X509Certificate2 withKey = caSigned.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa))
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes("some.pfx", withKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "and a password"));
    }
}
```

> or want to persist the private key in a .PEM file

This one is available in .NET Core 3.0 daily builds:

```
RSAParameters rsaParameters = default(RSAParameters);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("rsa.key"))
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    writer.WriteLine("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");

    writer.WriteLine(
        Convert.ToBase64String(
            rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(),
            Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));

    writer.WriteLine("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
}
```

PKCS#8 and encrypted PKCS#8 are also available.

On existing versions this requires using the RSAParameters and a ITU-T X.690 DER encoder.

> or want to store it in the MS certificate store together with the private key

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    using (X509Certificate2 caSigned = GetCASignedCert(rsa))
    using (X509Certificate2 withKey = caSigned.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa))
    using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        X509Certificate2 persisted = new X509Certificate2(
            withKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, ""),
            "",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        using (persisted)
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(persisted);
        }
    }
}
```

> or when I just want to have in memory and also assert HasPrivateKey.

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    using (X509Certificate2 caSigned = GetCASignedCert(rsa))
    {
        // Yes, this value can outlive both usings
        return caSigned.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a certificate hardware security module (HSM) such as a USB key, for example, it is not possible to "get" the private key because the HSM only provides an interface for using the private key. This is for security as once a private key is in a file or memory it is potentially obtainable by a third party.

Also .NET has, historically, not presented a flexible enough interface, although it is improving. As such a many software vendors use the more complete and well-maintained, Bouncy Castle API (http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) and you will find a lot of documentation around the web. Generally if .NET can't do it - bouncy castle will. Ironically an HSM requires .NET crypto access it's private key functionality on windows, but you usually encapsulate that somehow.

It is a steep learning curve using crypto APIs in general and it's unlikely that you will get much assistance without having a code example you want to make work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do know that HSMs will not allow you to get the private key, but they provide the means to perform the necessary cryptographic operations with the key, so they don't have to. I also do know Bouncy Castle, but one reason for my question is that I don't want to use it. The task I have at hand is to create a certificate with private key and make that accessible from the MS Certificate store. As I mentioned this is easily done with self-signed certificates, only the CA signed case is missing.