# Java asymmetric encryption: preferred way to store public/private keys

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

This code generates a pair of public/private keys:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
```

What I'd like to know is how do you usually store the public key:

**Option 1: store the bytes**

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
// ... write to file

// convert bytes back to public/private keys
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

What I don't like is to tie the code to concrete implementations such as `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and `X509EncodedKeySpec`.

**Option 2: store the modulus and exponent**

```
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec(privateKey,RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

// store modulus and exponent as BigIntegers
BigInteger modulus = pub.getModulus());
BigInteger exponent = pub.getPublicExponent());
// ... write to file

// recreate public key (the same applies to the private key)
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

The second option is easier to implement, but I don't know if it could be less performant.

Any advise ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In our applications, we store public and private keys in DER format so they can be used and manipulated outside java more easily.  In our case, the private keys do not have passwords on them.

To convert the private key to something more easily usable in java:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.der -outform DER
```

Then you can obtain an RSA private key directly by:

```
public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey(File privateKeyFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)privateKeyFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
    fis.read(keyBytes);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
    return privKey;
}
```

The public key is similar:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

and to read it:

```
public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKey(File publicKeyFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)publicKeyFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
    fis.read(keyBytes);
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)factory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    return pubKey;
}
```

Many people store then keystores.  For our purposes, we needed the same key to be shared across multiple applications in several different languages, and didn't want to duplicate the files on disk.

In either case, the performance shouldn't be a huge concern, because you're likely to store those keys in some sort of Singleton or cache instead of regenerating them each time.

Comment: DER is not really a format per se, just the way to encode ASN.1 objects.

Comment: For those looking to obtaining `public.der` directly from `id_rsa.pub` (public key) instead of `id_rsa` (private key) [this answer provides a way to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18290786/813810).

Answer (score 2):

You're actually storing the bytes in both cases whether you realize it or not. I suppose the correct answer is hinted at in @Brian M. Carr answer, which is to store the higher-level object in its most natural form. In the case of public keys, the obvious choices are as a PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey ASN.1 structure, DER-encoded, or as an X509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 structure, DER-encoded. The latter is what the Sun providers give you, which the sun class X509EncodedKeySpec supports. Similarly, the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec supports a private key format. Both these formats are standards, and are supported by openssl for example. Sun tends -- tended :( -- to support existing standards rather then define their own.

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful. I mark @Brian M. Carr answer as accepted because of the code examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a format for storing the keys, then I would choose a format that is expendable so that it doesn't break when you want to change encryption (when the old one gets to weak for example).

So i would store the bytes encoded as base64, together with a string that describes the format, "rsa" maybe.