# API requires SSH key, How exactly is this done in general?

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl

I'm looking to work with the Mobile Roadie API (I have thoughts on the platform but its not for here). http://mobileroadie.com/dev/speakers/create You'll notice it requires SSH and that the key has to be in the url. The example key is `4d4ba30d73b77f7` How is that key created using PHP? Would they (Mobile Roadie) have to receive that specific key I presume? But how could one send the private key to them?

I'm also presuming that an adaption of this SO question will do: [Generate SSH keypair form PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648337/generate-ssh-keypair-form-php)

I'm new to cURL and I'm intrigued.

Comment: It says SSL, not SSH. And the key is something you only get from them.

Comment: @mario god your right, okay great thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create an account you will be provided with the keys required. You do not create it yourself.