# Does .pem file contain both private and public keys?

Tags: security, ssl, ssh, openssl

I am wondering if PEM-files contain both private and public keys? What does "PEM" stand for?

Comment: related: [Convert pem key to ssh-rsa format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011572/537554)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

A PEM file may contain just about anything including a public key, a private key, or both, because a PEM file is not a standard. In effect PEM just means the file contains a base64-encoded bit of data. It is called a PEM file by allusion to the old **P**rivacy-**E**nhanced **M**ail standards which preceded S/MIME as a mail security standard. These standards specified the format of various keys and messages in a particular base64 format. See [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) for example.

Typically a PEM file contains a base64 encoded key or certificate with header and footer lines of the form `-----BEGIN <whatever>-----` and `-----END <whatever>----`. Over time there have evolved many possibilities for `<whatever>`, including private keys, public keys, X509 certificates, PKCS7 data, files containing multiple certificates, files containing both the private key and the X509 certificate, PKCS#10 certificate signing requests, ...

[RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) has been written to document this de facto format.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the abbreviation stands for

Comment: @hek2mgl The abbreviation was originally for _PEM Encapsulation Mechanism_, according to the explanation in mentioned RFC 7468.

Comment: @not2savvy: RFC 7469 does not say *PEM* is an abbreviation for *PEM Encapsulation Mechanism*.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Quoting from [RFC 4768, Introduction, page 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#page-3): _The tradition within the RFC series can be traced back to Privacy-
   Enhanced Mail (PEM) [RFC1421], based on a proposal by Marshall Rose
   in Message Encapsulation [RFC934].  Originally called "PEM
   encapsulation mechanism", [...]_

Comment: @not2savvy: Exactly; PEM = Privacy Enhanced Mail.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk …and originally called _PEM Encapsulation Mechanism_ if you continue to read the quote.

Comment: @not2savvy: Yes, that's the encapsulation mechanism, but it doesn't say PEM is an abbreviation for PEM encapsulation mechanism. It's not a recursive acronym like GNU.

Answer (score 34):

You can [decode](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html) your [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) formatted [x509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout
```

[PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail) certificate [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files) public key only **or** private key only **or** both.

---

For the following [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-enhanced_Electronic_Mail#Examples):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

you will get:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 0 (0x0)
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = BE, O = GnuTLS, OU = GnuTLS certificate authority, ST = Leuven, CN = GnuTLS certificate authority
        Validity
            Not Before: May 23 20:38:21 2011 GMT
            Not After : Dec 22 07:41:51 2012 GMT
        Subject: C = BE, O = GnuTLS, OU = GnuTLS certificate authority, ST = Leuven, CN = GnuTLS certificate authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:52:d8:8d:23:8a:e3:67:d7:86:36:b1:20:0b:09:
                    7d:c8:c9:ba:a2:20:95:2f:c5:4a:63:fa:83:5f:ce:
                    78:2f:8f:f3:62:ca:fd:b7:f7:80:56:9d:6e:17:b9:
                    0e:11:4c:48:b2:c0:af:3b:59:17:16:30:68:09:07:
                    99:17:fe:dd:a7
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F0:B4:81:FE:98:12:BF:B5:28:B9:64:40:03:CB:CC:1F:66:4E:28:03
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:20:31:ae:c0:3d:4a:3f:21:be:85:17:fc:f0:c7:b2:
         31:07:2a:38:56:43:d1:36:d5:95:e1:7e:52:c0:06:43:87:a7:
         02:21:00:97:8c:0e:b8:3c:0a:41:af:ae:a5:cf:06:7e:d5:c4:
         d8:2f:ff:e2:62:80:34:10:ba:22:dd:35:81:46:93:22:9a
```

To understand difference between `Public Key Algorithm` and `Signature Algorithm` sections read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141661/whats-the-difference-between-public-key-algorithm-and-signature-algorithm-i) (both are public).