# Installing SSL on XAMPP with these files

Tags: ssl

I was asked to install SSL on `XAMPP 5.5.38` while being given some **.pem** files.

To my understanding, these files are the certificates. Problem is, I have no solid idea how to use these files for installation. How do I approach this? Should I convert it to `.crt` files first? I was told that **.pem** files could be used in `xampp` but I'm not entirely sure myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Does .pem file contains both private and public keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539644/685326) for details about PEM file.

Provided that the PEM file you got contains both public certificate and private key (you can confirm by checking its content), you can use the same file for both `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` and it should work.

Comment: only files I got are cert.pem , chain.pem,, fullchain.pem and privkey.pem

Comment: @mrkenalano Then you already have the files separated. `SSLCertificateFile` is a cert, `SSLCertificateKeyFile` is a private key. Only these 2 are required. You don't have to convert them into .crt or .key. It should work fine with .pem file too.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Still couldn't install the .pem files that I have. This is making me nuts lol.

Comment: @mrkenalano Does your first line of `cert.pem` says `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `privkey.pem` says `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` or `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`? Are there any other sections within these 2 files?

Comment: Yes. They begin with the things that you said. And some other numbers and letters inside the ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- and ----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----. Sorry if I'm somewhat being of a hassle. I am not experienced enough to know these kinds of stuff. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my questions.

Comment: @mrkenalano Then it should work. Unless the way you configured your config file for apache server was incorrect which is difficult to help with without further information.