# meteor connect to remote mongodb error self signed certificate

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to connect my meteor app to mongodb cloud in scalegrid.

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://admin:PASSWORD@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true meteor run
```

but got error like this :

```
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR) MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [sg-brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017] on first connect [Error: self signed certificate
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
W20200510-10:53:22.340(7)? (STDERR)   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
W20200510-10:53:22.341(7)? (STDERR)   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
W20200510-10:53:22.341(7)? (STDERR) }]
```

error happen after I add 
`import '../imports/api/posts';` in `main.js`

---- EDITED from meteor forum

I have mongodb database cluster in scalegrid, but I can't connect to it with just like this :

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://admin:password@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true meteor run
```

I tried to use simple mongo connection in terminal

```
mongo mongodb://admin:password@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true
```

and stil cant connect with same error : 
`SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate`

and I tried to make it like this :

```
mongo mongodb://admin:password@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true --ssl --sslCAFile ./.crt
```

and it works!!!

the problem now, i cant add `--ssl --sslCAFile ./.crt` in `MONGO_URL` like this, because it makes error :

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://admin:password@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true --ssl --sslCAFile ./.crt meteor run
```

how to add ssl cert to mongo url?

---

new update I tried :

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://admin:password@SG-Brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/admin?ssl=true,ssl_ca_certs=./.crt meteor run
```

and got error :

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [sg-brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to sg-brain-77777.servers.mongodirector.com:27017 closed
```

Comment: Does your server use a self signed certificate?

Comment: hi @Jankapunkt I update the case, hope it can help to solve

Answer (score 3):

#### The Solution:

You need to [specify the MongoDB SSL CA Certificate in Meteor settings](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_connection_options_settings).

#### Step by Step Guide:

1. Login to Scalegrid and select the cluster for your Meteor app.
2. Scroll to the bottom, and click `Get SSL CA Cert`
   [image]
3. Copy the text into a new file `private/scalegrid-cert.pem`

> NOTE: it's safe to commit `private/scalegrid-cert.pem` to your repo
>   because it contains a public key. Bear in mind some `.pem` files
>   [include private keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539644/3048733)
>   and should never be added to a repo.

4. Add the following to your Meteor settings environment variable

```
  "packages": {
    "mongo": {
      "options": {
        "tls": true,
        "tlsCAFileAsset": "scalegrid-cert.pem"
      }
    }
  }
```

> NOTE: it's `"tlsCAFileAsset": "scalegrid-cert.pem"`not `"tlsCAFileAsset": "private/scalegrid-cert.pem"`. See [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_connection_options_settings) for why.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me to connect to IBM Cloud Mongo.

Comment: The packages section in the environment only works for Meteor 1.10+. If you're on an earlier version of Meteor (tested with 1.7), you can specify the cert in the URL string with '&sslCAFile=./private/scalegrid-cert.pem'. Upload the file in the same manner as described.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify TLS/SSL options in the connection URI string is different from how it is specified for the mongo shell.

You have two options if you want to specify this on the connection string itself.

1. You can use the `tlsCAFile` option in the connection string. See - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.tlsCAFile
   This would help you specify the file path to the CA certificate file.
2. The other option is to use the `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates`. See - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.tlsAllowInvalidHostnames If this is set to `true`, then you wouldn't need to specify the CA cert file at all.

Note that both these options are available only for MongoDB 4.2 and above. Also, read the documentation warning about `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates`.

Comment: thanks for your response, but it not work well in meteor mongo_url

Comment: did you see meteor documentation environment about mongo_url?

Comment: unfortunately yes :(