# Capifony forward_agent not working. Asks for GitHub password and fails

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano, ubuntu-14.04, capifony

I am using capifony to deploy a symfony2 web app onto Ubuntu. I have the following in my deploy.rb:

```
set :repository, "git@github.com:Username/Repo.git"
set :branch,      "develop"
set :scm_verbose, true
set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/Users/myuser/Sites/file.pem"]
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = ["publickey"]
```

Capifony is able to ssh in but then asks for a GitHub password during the deploy. I enter the password correctly but it then give me the following authentication fail error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://UserName@github.com/UserName/Repo.git/'
```

I don't know why it is asking for my Github password, and why it doesn't use agent forwarding to ssh to github?

I have added my public key from the server to GitHub but I am a bit confused about these keys, and my local keys? does it forward my local key or does it use the server one? What permissions do I need to set etc?

I am using capifony v2.8.6
I recently had to reinstall ruby and capifony die to upgrading to El Capitan which stopped capifony from working altogether. This is when my problems started.
I am deploying to Ubuntu 14.04

I have tried editing /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the server and adding

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Then restarting ssh, but this has no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Capifony anymore and cannot comment yet so I try to answer :)

First, if you deploy from your local machine (your Mac), check :

- your ssh-agent is started,
- you can git clone one of your github repo
- you can ssh to your Ubuntu server

Then you could just set this two line below.

`default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true`

No need to set other `ssh_options` nor to tweak you ssh server config , it might be very confusing.

Second, you can test if ssh forwarding is working for the selected environment by creating a simple rake tasks inside your project :

`namespace :ssh do
    desc "Check if agent forwarding is working"
    task :forwarding do
        on roles(:all) do |h|
            if test("env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK")
                info "Agent forwarding is up to #{h}"
            else
                error "Agent forwarding is NOT up to #{h}"
            end
        end
    end
end`

And test with a `cap [env] ssh:forwarding`

Finally, if you reinstalled ruby/capifony recently, try to make the switch to Capistrano v3 and its [Symfony gem](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony) instead, it really worth a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I have upgraded to capistrano v3 and symfony gem. I am looking at authentication docs here - http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/ I am a bit confused about the difference between my EC2 .pem file and the id_rsa ssh key. Do I need/can I use both?

Comment: I have started a new question based on my capistrano 3 script - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105995/capistrano-3-deploy-fails-connecting-to-github-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: I think you have to convert your Amazon pem file into regular ssk key and add it to your github account, see here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421096/deploying-to-ec2-instance-failing-when-access-github-private-repo