# How to convert RSA key to ssh-rsa

Tags: objective-c, encryption, ssh, openssl, openssh

I am trying to convert a generated public RSA key to a SSH using Apples security framework.

Here is the code I am using for generating the key pairs:

```
- (void)generatePrivateKey {
    NSDictionary *privateKeyAttr = @{(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES,
                                     (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: self.privateTag};
    NSDictionary *publicKeyAttr = @{(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent: @YES,
                                    (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: self.publicTag};


    NSDictionary *keyPairAttr = @{(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @1024,
                                  (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType: (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                                  (__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: privateKeyAttr,
                                  (__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs: publicKeyAttr};

    SecKeyRef publicKey;
    SecKeyRef privateKey;

    SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey);
}

- (NSString *)getPublicKey {
    NSString *contents = [self keyForTag:self.publicTag];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", contents];
}

- (NSString *)getPrivateKey {
    NSString *contents = [self keyForTag:self.privateTag];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n%@\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", contents];
}

- (NSString *)keyForTag:(NSData *)tag {
    NSDictionary *queryKey = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
                                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType: (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                                      (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: @YES};

    // Get the key bits.
    CFDataRef keyBits;
    OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryKey, (CFTypeRef *)&keyBits);
    NSData *passDat = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)keyBits;

    if (sanityCheck != noErr) {
        passDat = nil;
    }

    NSString *contents = [passDat base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return contents;
}
```

Then I end up with a private key like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Putting this into `ssh-keygen` produces the following public key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f test.p12 -y
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQC7VWIi0kXyx/UCGG91iGqKjohRLIj9hp44Xwd/pIApBHo38/noUeqN07S4oGgx47zZthg3zKFP90eEdKKOXZ0yuQKOy+yB5YAYg7e9FVvxfXCOVrGaZohh37HLUql/bdOzTK6/Upjl0ZZNYpxWyfIZ/8jKCAaTG6BhPQhLmWxCQw==
```

My question is how to do the `ssh-keygen` with the Apple Security framework or OpenSSH?

**UPDATE:**

I am now using OpenSSL directly and get a valid `RSA` key. However the conversion is still not working correctly:

```
- (NSString *)publicKey {
    RSA *rsa = self.rsaPrivateKey;

    // Encode the "ssh-rsa" string
    NSMutableData *sshrsa = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    const char start[] = {0, 0, 0, 7, 's', 's', 'h', '-', 'r', 's', 'a'};
    [sshrsa appendBytes:start length:sizeof(start)];

    // Encode the RSA encoding exponent e
    {
        const char *e = BN_bn2dec(rsa->e);
        NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lu", strlen(e)] ;
        [sshrsa appendData:[length dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [sshrsa appendBytes:e length:strlen(e)];
    }

    // Encode the RSA modul n
    {
        const char *n = BN_bn2dec(rsa->n);
        NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04lu", strlen(n)] ;
        [sshrsa appendData:[length dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [sshrsa appendBytes:n length:strlen(n)];
    }

    return [sshrsa base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];;
}
```

The new key is

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAG4AAAATYwvdcavn8AALOV1CoAAAAG4HHTGr5/AAAwyNcavn8AAPAq1xq+fwAAkPBhBwEAAAC2hnJUVxt7AO3JLixNzOwBALilG75/AABQsaUbvn8AAJC2pRu+fwAAELGlG75/AABZVMwDAQAAAECupRu+fwAAsJsHXP9/AAAIC7kDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHB3QAAAAAAA2IRA8A/wGr5/AAAAUvAavn8AAJBV4xq+fwAAAFLwGr5/AACQc4Ybvn8AAABS8Bq+fwAAAI4CHr5/AACQc4Ybvn8AAJBzhhu+fwAA4DGwG75/AACfAZIEAQAAAABS8Bq+fwAAUACBG75/AAA9j24JAQAAAFAAgRu+fwAAAFLwGr5/AADgMbAbvn8AAAAAAAAAAAAA4A==
```

which is way longer than it should be:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQC+gK0cEEgn/dDk+Sf/AdQtHp2rJoG7DxMuw2hL0+96rdKeixXVXWCE8GqMg7xIU8kSn0lrfcCJDhVBkArmlnlrZDfv1lTItBU7PvV4eDLT+3kApoqYMUmmo/ecDRyAaaOecoVZTl27RZghXcS7yxABlbVhYLzJEywOi46A9yBMFQ==
```

Comment: Could you update how did you end up generating the SSH key?. I am stuck with the same problem as you ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta: At least part of an answer, but I don't know ObjC so making CW for improvement.

Note: This is nearly a duplicate of [Convert pem key to ssh-rsa format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format/21290281) except that is in C not ObjC, and it starts from a publickey file instead of a privatekey file -- but OpenSSL's in-memory structure for an RSA key is the same for a publickey or privatekey, with privatekey-specific fields ignored for a publickey.
And it can be improved.

Your code (apparently) generates a length value in *decimal* as 4 digits and a *decimal* representation of the magnitude (without sign since the value is always positive) for each of e and n, but unbase64'ing your posted output doesn't show any of these actually included in the result, which after the correct initial part matching your `start` appears to be garbage, and I don't know why. You may need some ObjC debugging help there.

Anyway, the **correct encoding** is 4-byte *binary* (bigendian) length, followed by a *binary* bigendian representation of the value in two's complement, which requires adding a leading zero byte for a positive number in the range 2<sup>8k</sup>/2 to 2<sup>8k</sup>-1; this is usually the case for n because RSA key size is usually chosen a multiple of 8 (actually a power of 2 or small multiple thereof). e is rarely chosen this way although it can be. See "string" and "mpint" in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251#section-5 .

You can do this as in #1011572 by calling `BN_bn2bin` to get the binary bigendian magnitude into a large-enough buffer, then encode the 4-byte length, possible 1-byte sign and magnitude, again into a large-enough buffer. Or OpenSSL can actually do much of this for you; call `BN_bn2mpi` with a large-enough buffer and it will do the length, possible sign and magnitude.

How to allocate and manage the buffer(s?) in ObjC I leave to you or someone else. Do note that both the length fields and the value parts can and frequently will use the zero byte as a valid byte value; it must not be treated as a terminator or otherwise special. A little googling suggests to me this *may* be a problem for `NSString` but I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `ssh-keygen` does it will probably be SSH specific and Apple's  Security framework might not cover that.

It might be worth to check what `do_print_public` in [ssh-keygen.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-7.1/openssh/ssh-keygen.c) and `write_key` in [key.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-7.1/openssh/key.c) does and just copy that.

Or consider using libssh2's [libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile](http://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile.html) function.

Comment: I put an update on my question as it is still not working. I can't figure out where ssh-keygen does the transformation. When I use the same code I end up with something completely different.