# ssh-keygen and openssl gives two different public keys

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, ssh-keys, key-pair

Is it possible that ssh-keygen & openssl can generate two different public keys from same private key? Command `ssh-keygen -y -f ./my.key` gives (contents after `ssh-rsa` in the same line) different public key to the one generated (contents between `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`) with command `openssl rsa -in my.key -pubout` .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Nice! Glad to find this question answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same key but different representations. OpenSSL uses X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo in ASN.1, usually (including here) wrapped in PEM; OpenSSH (except 'rsa1' keys for SSHv1 which is broken and you shouldn't use) uses the XDR-like SSH wire format, in base64.

Dupe or neardupe:
[Convert pem key to ssh-rsa format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format)
[RSA Public Key format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749858/rsa-public-key-format)
[Convert RSA public key to RSA DER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162155/convert-rsa-public-key-to-rsa-der)
[Converting an OpenSSL generated RSA public key to OpenSSH format (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524121/converting-an-openssl-generated-rsa-public-key-to-openssh-format-php)
[How to convert RSA key to ssh-rsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998383/how-to-convert-rsa-key-to-ssh-rsa)
[How to store/retrieve RSA public/private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193529/how-to-store-retrieve-rsa-public-private-key) (buried in the middle)
and less obvious cross-stack https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42268/how-do-i-get-the-rsa-bit-length-with-the-pubkey-and-openssl