# How to Calculate Fingerprint From SSH DSA Public Key in Java?

Tags: java, ssh, public-key, java-security, dsa

Similar to question [How to Calculate Fingerprint From SSH RSA Public Key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059782/how-to-calculate-fingerprint-from-ssh-rsa-public-key-in-java) , I would like to know how to Calculate Fingerprint for a DSA Public Key.
I've got the dsaPublicKey object.

```
DSAPublicKey dsaPublicKey = (DSAPublicKey) publicKey;
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the directions in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059782/how-to-calculate-fingerprint-from-ssh-rsa-public-key-in-java) together with the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/DSAPublicKey.html) for `DSAPublicKey` should be sufficient for you.